# BeagleBone Black UART1 enabled, but does not send or receive data

Tags: linux, serial-port, uart, beagleboneblack

I have (finally) managed to get UART1 going on my BBB using the instructions here:

http://tenderlovemaking.com/2014/01/19/enabling-ttyo1-on-beaglebone.html

Doing `ls -la /dev/ttyO*` gives

```
crw--w---- 1 root tty     248, 0 Sep 22 14:50 /dev/ttyO0
crw-rw---- 1 root dialout 248, 1 Sep 22 14:50 /dev/ttyO1
```

but I cannot seem to write or read anything.

```
echo "wibble" > /dev/ttyO1
```

does nothing (I ran `screen /dev/ttyO1 115200` in another terminal window). Is there a further step to actually get data flowing through the serial port?

Note: Beaglebone revision is B6.

Comment: Your `echo` and `screen` "test" could only work if you installed or setup a loopback (or local echo but that doesn't test any data transfer).  But you don't mention that you did. You don't mention setting any port parameters (i.e. the baud rate, char length, parity) prior to your "testing" on the `echo` side.  But you specify a baud rate on the `screen` side.

Comment: Thanks @sawdust, I also tried with hyperterminal on my development PC, connected with a custom cable into the cape header, with similar results. Various settings (baud, char size, stop bits, parity...)

Comment: The simplest test of the transmission functionality of the UART requires an oscilloscope. Send data from the processor side of the UART.  Use the 'scope to see if there's TTL data on the output.  Is there RS232 data after the transceiver (aka level shifter)?  is there data at the other end of the cable, at the RxD of the remote UART?  For the receive function at your UART, apply the same testing but start at the remote end's TxD or use a loopback.